# when is fixed length encoding better than huffman?

Tags: encoding, huffman-code

For the word "sleeplessness" Huffman encoding is 27 bits while Fixed length encoding is 39

Is there a word or a general condition in which Huffman will need more bits than Fixed length encoding?

Comment: Yes, when you use characters which are unlikely to use based on the huffman tree you are using. What exactly do you want to know or where do you struggle? Which huffman tree are you using in your case and how did you come up with 27 bits and 39 bits?

Comment: @Progman I made a tree based on Huffman algorithm out of the word sleeplessness (so it only has the letters s,l,e,p,n) . If I make a new Huffman tree for the word I use, in which case(which word) I will need more bits using my Huffman tree than Fixed length encoding

Comment: Then no. The "worst case" is equal distribution of characters, which result in a balanced tree. For example the word "abcd" will be transmitted as `00 01 10 00` in huffman encoding, which would be the same with fixed length encoding.

Answer (score 2):

A Huffman coding using the probability of the symbols in the message will never need more bits than a fixed-length coding, though *only* if we ignore the bits required to transmit a description of the code itself. The Huffman code description plus the Huffman-coded message for short messages will often be larger than a fixed-length code that requires no description.